# What is the best approach to storing and deploying environment variable files to Node.js if they are excluded from version control?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Firstly a tiny bit of background: I have a MEAN stack application running on Bitnami Ubuntu, on AWS. I have a .env file with API keys etc in it, that is excluded from my repo using .gitignore.

I understand the main approaches to initialising the application to pick up the .env file, but none of the articles which describe these comment on (1) what options are there to deploy your .env to your server if it's not in your git repo, and (2) if it's not stored in version control, where might it be best to keep that .env file so that it's secure?

Others experiences of this would be very valuable. I couldn't find anything similar on Google, SO or SF.

Thanks.

Comment: The idea is that you use versioning for maintaining your code base and *”configuration management”* to govern  which release should be deployed where and with what settings.

Comment: This depends on how you're deploying your app. But there is always somewhere to put the environment variables.

Comment: I've got more of a handle on what to search for now. Thank you both very much.